# Why are backslashes displayed as "₩" (Korean won sign, “W”+strikethrough) in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, css

I have scoured the internet for over 2 hours trying to find a solution that works to resolve this.  I am trying to do a space escape in a .css file in Notepad++ and it just keeps showing this weird W thing (which I found out is the Korean currency symbol for "Won").

I've attempted all of the obvious and suggested fixes I was able to find - reinstalled Notepad++, changed the language settings, etc.  It only does this in CSS files and it only does it in Notepad++.  Another odd thing is that "Find"(Cntrl+F) results for "\" show this as the only instance in the file.

[image]

I want it to display

```
#status.En\ panne{...}
```

My two questions are:
1) Is there a way to resolve this? 
2) Will just leaving it there still act as a space escape?

Comment: Check Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative (Windows 7), what is set for "Language for non-Unicode programs"? I know if that's set to Japanese the \ appears as a Yen sign. It's just cosmetic though, it should still be \ in the file.

Comment: Did you try the 'encoding' menu item in notepadd++ and change the encoding?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and answers.  I will check all of these out and post my findings.

Comment: @DBZ_A Yes I changed that and the font around several times to see if I can get any results.

Comment: @baochan it shows as English (United States)

Comment: It sounds like somehow it's displaying text with a Korean encoding. Check @DBZ_A's suggestion or Settings -> Style Configurator, maybe you're defaulting to a Korean font?

Comment: There is a convert encoding option also in the encoding menu, you might need to make a copy of the file and experiment with that too? I think since this is code you can convert to ANSI. Also please post the result once it is resolved :)

Comment: @baochan I checked all of those.  My languages are all set to English and my font is set to Arial.

Comment: @DBZ_A I will be sure to post the results once I've resolved this, if I do in fact resolve it.  The problem persists when making an entirely new file and copying the CSS code to it.  It shows up just fine.  But the *second* I change the language to CSS it creates the Won symbol rather than the \

Comment: Posted an answer, for some reason my Notepad++ is set up the same way and I get the same error for CSS. It's a problem with the default font for the CSS style.

Comment: @Mkalafut: It's not you, it's a bug in Notepad++. http://i.stack.imgur.com/BxuJQ.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was able to reproduce the problem, not sure how this happened:

In Settings -> Style Configurator, choose CSS, and TAG. The font name defaults to "Batang", a Korean font. Select Font Name and choose the first (blank) selection, and Save&Close. That should fix it.

Comment: yaay! :) that relief when you get an answer for a puzzle-question like this!

Comment: Yep, it sure does.  Thanks for the info everybody!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen before on MP3 players, and my experience shows that this issue is caused by the software using the wrong character encoding to display the text.

Is Notepad++ set to use the correct character encoding? Regardless, this is most likely a character *display* issue; what is stored in the file is probably the correct binary code for the backslash character and the code should work correctly.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, the issue is likely due to Notepad++ using the wrong font for the CSS syntax highlighting. I can reproduce this myself with the text `foo.bar\`, so I'm pretty sure this is a bug in Notepad++.

[image: Notepad++ bug: backslash displayed as backslash sign]